# How can I schedule my selenium script to run on a particular day of the week at a specific time?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, scheduled-tasks

I have Selenium Script written in JAVA with TestNg framework. I want to run that script on a particular day of the week at a specific time. Can anyone please help me with the solution to this?

Comment: Depending on your operating system you should be able to schedule whatever program at whatever time on whatever day.

Comment: Two approaches: for [Windows](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-automated-task-using-task-scheduler-windows-10), for [Linux](https://opensource.com/article/17/11/how-use-cron-linux).

Answer (score 0):

Install **jenkins**, jenkins is very useful for continuous execution and scheduling.

Steps to schedule,

1. Create a new job
2. Pull your code repo : git/svn
3. Enter the command line arguments in the build section
4. Enable "Build periodically" option to schedule.
5. for Scheduling numbers, use this site, this is very useful : https://crontab.guru/

Eg :
H 4 * * 2   => At 04:05 on Every Tuesday.